# How to create a broken stream for a test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have this function and I want to test it. I want to test `stream.on('error', err => reject(err));` line, but don't know how to reach it. What could I input in this function to trigger the error throw? Thank you!

```
function streamToString(stream) {
  const chunks = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)));
    stream.on('error', err => reject(err));
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8')));
  });
}
```

Comment: In your test, create a new empty readable stream and call [.destroy()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readabledestroyerror) passing an error string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in nodejs and using jest you could Emit the error by your self like:

```js
function streamToString(stream) {
  const chunks = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.on("data", (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)));
    stream.on("error", (err) => reject(err));
    stream.on("end", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString("utf8")));
  });
}

test("broken stream", () => {
  let fs = require("fs");
  let stream = fs.createReadStream("file.txt");
  let res = streamToString(stream);
  stream.emit("error", "OH NO!");
  return expect(res).rejects.toMatch("OH NO!");
});

//or

test("broken stream", () => {
  let fs = require("fs");
  let stream = fs.createReadStream("file.txt");
  let res = streamToString(stream);
  stream.destroy("OH NO!");
  return expect(res).rejects.toMatch("OH NO!");
});
```

Comment: Tried both your variants, also tried destroying the stream before passing it to the function, but `err => reject(err));` is not covered by Jest, although test expect value you provided passes. Maybe I don't need the reject value at all, if I can catch the error on higher level?

Comment: You can not destroy the stream before you've created the Promise. You need to destroy it while the Promise is still unresolved/unrejected. Maybe you can share your jest test function in order ro help you better? :)

Comment: my tests are exactly those from your answer, I tried both of them.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change then ?